# How to add extra url to main dataSource (url to duplicated reserve database) to dinamically switch at runtime?

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

There is application on spring-boot
In production, there is two duplicated databases: main and reserve with full duplication.

If I have one dataSource with url to main-database, can I somehow add second url to reserve database?

When my main database will be broken, I want to switch reserve database url in same dataSource

Comment: As you are using oracle is there now RAC or Dataguard in place?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I use Dataguard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the Dataguard URL in the form of a TNS names entry (that you should get from the DBA).

Example:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@
    (
    DESCRIPTION=
      (
      ADDRESS_LIST=
        (LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
        (FAILOVER=ON)
        (
        ADDRESS=
          (PROTOCOL=TCP)
          (HOST=10.0.0.6)
          (PORT=1521)
        )
        (
        ADDRESS=
          (PROTOCOL=TCP)
          (HOST=10.0.0.7)
          (PORT=1521)
        )
      )
      (
      CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVICE_NAME=mySID.nowhere.org)
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
      )
     )
```

You don't need two datasources. The failover will be handled by Dataguard.

Comment: Do I need to write this in appliation.props on my application side or I have to write this on oracle-side?

Comment: That's the spring.datasource.url you have to put in on one line